# How to change default listening port when use gitbook to serve a site?

Tags: node.js

When issue the command gitbook serve, server will listen at tcp port 4000. How to customize the port ?
Case is that: when to two books at same time, a collision happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify port number flag. Ex: use port number 3000

```
gitbook --port 3000 serve
```

Comment: Thanks, zaynetro. You solved my problem. Could you please give me a link on what options do gitbook provide?  I've search through [github](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook), but nothing useful found.

Comment: @wanglf, I actually just searched the code [link](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/blob/master/bin/gitbook.js#L30)

Answer (score 6):

lrport defaul to 35729, port default to 4000.
So you can change both two ports and serve as many books as you want.

eg:

one:

```
gitbook --lrport 35730 --port 4001 serve
```

another:

```
gitbook --lrport 35731 --port 4002 serve
```

---

#### Note

```sh
# gitbook help
...
    serve [book] [output]       serve the book as a website for testing
        --port                  Port for server to listen on (Default is 4000)
        --lrport                Port for livereload server to listen on (Default is 35729)
        --[no-]watch            Enable file watcher and live reloading (Default is true)
        --[no-]live             Enable live reloading (Default is true)
        --[no-]open             Enable opening book in browser (Default is false)
        --browser               Specify browser for opening book (Default is )
        --log                   Minimum log level to display (Default is info; Values are debug, info, warn, error, disabled)
        --format                Format to build to (Default is website; Values are website, json, ebook)
...
```